# Making Random Choices from multiple lists effectively

Tags: python, random

I'm implementing Wilson's Algorithm, which uses random walks along graphs. So, at every step, I currently do run random.random.choice on the list of neighbors of my current vertex. However, this is obviously slow. If I was making random choices from the same list repeatedly, I could use numpy's np.random.choice with a larger size, but since the length of neighbors is not the same for all vertices, I am not sure how to do this.

```
def wilsons(G):
    nodes = list(G.keys())
    v1 = random.choice(nodes)
    v2 = random.choice(nodes)
    V = [v1]
    v = v1
    while v != v2:
        v = random.choice(G[v])
        if v in V:
            V = V[0:V.index(v)]
        V.append(v)

    out = {}
    out[V[0]] = [V[1]] if len(V) > 1 else []
    out[V[-1]] = [V[-2]] if len(V) > 1 else []
    for i in range(1,len(V)-1):
        out[V[i]] = [V[i-1], V[i+1]]
    U = set(V)

    nnodes = len(nodes)
    outlen = len(V)
    while outlen < nnodes:
        v = random.choice(list(set(nodes)-U))
        V = [v]
        while v not in U:
            v = random.choice(G[v])
            if v in V:
                V = V[0:V.index(v)]
            V.append(v)
        U.update(set(V))
        outlen += len(V)-1

        out[V[0]] = [V[1]]

        out[V[-1]].append(V[-2])
        for i in range(1,len(V)-1):
            out[V[i]] = [V[i-1], V[i+1]]
    return out
```

Comment: why did you remove the code? that was the interesting part!

Comment: alright I put it back, I thought it just added levels of confusion to my question

Comment: I'd suggest running a profiler to see where the code is spending time, it's often in unintuitive places.  for example, doing `random.choice(l)` (where `l` is a list of 10 `int`s) is faster than your `list(set(l) - {2})`

Comment: currently random.choice takes half of my time, and a third is spent within the function. I'll make a fix for the first part though.

Comment: wow! have you tried other random number generators?  xoshiro or pcg are much faster then the Mersenne Twister used by default, but I'm struggling to find any nice Python libraries for them

Comment: I have not looked into it deeply, a good coder I know said that one reason is that random.choice is needless precise in it's generation, as it makes a random draw from (0,1) which is strong enough for much larger lists than mine, which of length 5 to 6 usually

Comment: I think that commentators on the Code Review stack exchange would have helpful comments. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/